# Is it possible not to use absolute position?

Tags: css

I want to add animation to the button with the following code https://codepen.io/chrisota/pen/bNdRaM
but altered it a bit like this

```
 a::before{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    content:'';
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    width: 30px*2;
    height: 20px*2;
    line-height: 30px*2;
    left: -30px/2;
    text-align: center;
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease-out;
    z-index: -1;
}
  
 a:hover{
    color: #fff;}
  a:hover::before{
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 $width rgba($button-color,1);
    }
```

However,as far as I know absolute position is better not to use, but when I delete it, the button vanishes

```
<row>
<div class='col-5'>
a(href="http://www.dribbble.com/chrisota" title="Chris Ota Dribbble") <i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i> Dribbble
</div>
</row>
```

Comment: That's SCSS, which gets preprocessed into CSS. Just move the inner rule outside and make the selector `a:hover::before`

Comment: What is your style tag looks like? Does it have SCSS setup? https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sass

Comment: For what it's worth, `position:absolute` is a misnomer - it functions to position an entity relatively to it's nearest positioned ancestor. As the answerer below says, `position: absolute` is a beautiful, magical tool to use, it just gets a bad wrap because a lot of people don't understand how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: absolute` is a wonderful tool when wielded properly.

It truly shines in the `::before` and `::after` psuedo-elements.

When you set the position of the element to `relative` and the position of `::before` and `::after` to `absolute`, you can position your pseudo-elements relative to the element itself.

This allows you to do cool things like adding icons to your buttons for example.

Just make sure to set the `display` and `content` properties like below. You can add the `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties to move the element around.

```css
.some-class {
    position: relative;
}
.some-class::before {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    top: 10px; /* just an example */
    left: 10px; /* just an example */
    width: 32px; /* just an example */
    height: 32px; /* just an example */
}
```